# Need help converting the values in Switch..Case to output into XML

Tags: c#, xml

I created a switch ..case for Event Code and I'm not sure how to translate the Event Codes into the XElement for Event Status

Here is the EventCode class

```
public class EventCode
    {
        public enum EvCodes {Delivered, DispatchedForDelivery, 
        DepartedFromTerminal, ArrivedAtDestinationTerminal};
        public static void Main()
        {
            string val = "Dispatched For Delivery";
            switch ((EvCodes)Enum.Parse(typeof(EvCodes), val.Replace(" ", "")))
            {
                case EvCodes.DispatchedForDelivery:
                case EvCodes.Delivered:
                    Console.WriteLine("OD");
                    break;
                case EvCodes.DepartedFromTerminal:
                    Console.WriteLine("L1");
                    break;

            }

        }
```

Here is the EventStatus is what I'm trying to convert or read the value:

```
rspxml.Root.Add(
new XElement("API", "4.0"),
new XElement("PackageTrackingInfo",
new XElement("TrackingNumber", prc.ProNumber)
),

new XElement("TrackingEventHistory", 
prc.History.Cast<Saia.Data.General.Shipment.HistoryItem>().Select(item => 
new XElement("TrackingEventDetail",
new XElement("EventStatus", prc.History,
new XElement("EventReason", prc.History),
new XElement("EventDateTime", prc.History)
```

Would it be something like this:

```
new XElement("EventStatus", EventCode.EvCodes.Delivered
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method that accepts an EvCodes value as input and returns the String you wish to add to the XElement, something like:

```
public static string ToXml(this EventCode.EvCodes value)
{
  switch(value)
  {
    case EvCodes.DispatchedForDelivery:
    case EvCodes.Delivered:
      return "OD";
    case EvCodes.DepartedFromTerminal:
      return "L1";
  }
}
```

When you wish to write this to XML you would then invoke the extension method as:

```
new XElement("EventStatus", EventCode.EvCodes.Delivered.ToXml());
```

Comment: Get a few errors on this:  1.'Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; EvMapper is a nested class 
 2. 'The name 'EvCodes' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Well, the compiler is not wrong

The extension method was a suggestion, if you would like to use it then it would need to go into a separate static class, if not you could remove the 'this' keyword from the value parameter and put the ToXml method in the same class as you're calling it from

I do not know what EvMapper is - it's not in your sample code